# Outlook .ics not appearing as standard calendar invite using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, outlook, google-calendar-api

I am trying to send .ics files using laravel 8 to outlook in the standard way that a normal meeting invite would be sent. I have tried copying exact invitations and many different methods and nothing seems to work here. I believe it is something to do with how I am sending vs what I am sending. I would like to use the Laravel Mail API. I have provided some code below for what I have done so far. I copied an exact .ics that worked on my regular outlook to base the file off, but still not working correctly.

I would appreciate any help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Models\Meeting;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MeetingInviteMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */

    public function build(){

            $from_name = "Company Name"; 
            $from_address = "info@example.com";
            $to_name = "Receiver Name";
            $to_address = "name@example.com";
            $startTime = $start->format("m/d/Y H:i:s"); //these are carbon datetimes
            $endTime = $end->format("m/d/Y H:i:s");
            $subject = "Meeting Subject";
            $location = "Zoom Dial-in TBD";
            $domain = 'example.com'; 



       
 $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20210504T000631Z
DESCRIPTION: XXXXX 
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20210503T210000
DTSTAMP:20210504T000611Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20210503T200000
LAST-MODIFIED:20210504T000631Z
LOCATION:https://zoom.us/j/**************************
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:My Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:20210504T000611Z-95378197685@fe80:0:0:0:1080:3fff:fe1c:150dens5
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 16.0.13901.20436">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted
     from text/plain format -->\n\n<P><FONT SIZE=2>Company is inviti
    ng you to a scheduled Zoom meeting.</FONT>\n</P>\n\n<P><FONT SIZE=2>Join Z
    oom Meeting</FONT>\n\n<BR><FONT SIZE=2><A HREF="https://zoom.us/j/*******">https://zoom.us/j/*******</A></FONT>\n</P>\n\n<P><FONT SIZE=2>Mee
    ting ID: ******</FONT>\n\n<BR><FONT SIZE=2>Passcode: ******</FONT>\
    n</P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
';


              return $this->from('info@example.com')
               ->markdown('emails.meeting-invite') //markdown is not significant, not even sure its needed but laravel requires it
                ->attachData($ical, 'invite.ics', [
                    'mime' => 'text/calendar;charset=UTF-8;method=REQUEST',
                ]);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself-changing "method" to "request" from publish made it finally work on my end